# how to prevent tab in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can we stop prevent blur or tabbing for 5 second in input field.then after 5 second user can tab from one field to another.I use `off` and `on` function but it is not working .here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/GV3YY/99/

```
$("input").off("blur");

setTimeout(function(){
$("input").on("blur");
},5000)
```

Comment: did you try ``e.keycode``?

Comment: Have you tried setting the HTML `tabindex`  attribute to `-1`? `$(selector).attr('tabindex', '-1');`.

Comment: for 5 second user can type anything in input field .but not move focus to button.but only after 5 second he can move focus to button

Answer (score 0):

You need to "lock" the inputs when they is focused and use setTimeout to "unlock" it after 5 seconds. A naive implementation could look something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/my7wk6gj/2/

Update: Now pseudo prevents bluring by click. The blur still happens, but focus is returned to the original input until the 5 seconds have passed. I couldn't get `event.stopImmediatePropagation` to work for blur, so this is the next best thing...

```
var lockInput = false;
var focusTarget = null;
var lockTimeout = null;

$('input').on('focus', function (e) {
  if (lockTimeout) {
    return;
  }

  lockInput = true;
  lockTimeout = setTimeout(function () { lockInput = false; lockTimeout = null }, 5000)
}).on('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9 && lockInput) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}).on('blur', function (e) {
    console.log('blur')
  if (lockInput && focusTarget === null) {
    focusTarget = e.target;
    setTimeout(function () {
      focusTarget.focus();
      focusTarget = null;
    });
  }
});
```

The global variables are used only for the example, i'd advice against that.

Also, if you have a large number of inputs, i'd suggest using event delegation, instead of adding a listener to every one of them.

Comment: IT IS not correct..steps: run application change time 5 sec to 15 sec .type "abc" and use tab keyword ..it move it focus to button but it should not go to it before 15 sec .I need to prevent blur eeveent on input field

Comment: Your question was how to prevent tab for 5 seconds after the user focused an input. The code does what you asked for. Perhaps, spend some time writing a proper question instead of replying with "IT IS not correct"...

Comment: sorry ..but i thing this is my mistake

Comment: Note that this only stops the tab key, but the question asked about preventing blur - which would mean also stopping the user from leaving the field with a mouse click.

Comment: I've updated the answer to stop blurring via clicks. It will literally not let you blur outside of that input, until 5 seconds have passed. This is really bad user experience in my opinion. Use with caution...